# Validar ingreso de datos duplicados en Array con push -JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Mi problema es que quiero insertar valores que no sean repetidos al momento de realizar un push

Este es mi codigo :

```
addAddress: function() {
            this.insertAddresses.Adress = this.address_address
            this.insertAddresses.State = this.selectedStateAddress
            this.insertAddresses.City = this.selectedCityAddress
            if(this.insertAddresses.Adress !== "" && this.insertAddresses.State !== null && this.insertAddresses.City !== null) {
                let copia = Object.assign({}, this.insertAddresses);
                this.addresses.push(copia)
            }
            else
            {
                this.$message.error('Not enough data to add');
                return
            }
        },
```

Al momento de añadir un nuevo elemento a mi objeto, este me devuelve lo siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de darle otra vez en el boton agregar, este me agrega nuevamente los mismos valores, quiero relaizar una validacion para que los datos no sean iguales. ¿Como podria realizar esta  validacion de la manera correcta?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imagino que la repetición que no quieres añadir es cuando se repitan los tres campos juntos (direccion, pais y ciudad). Si es así, puedes utilizar la función reduce para crear un indice acumulando en un objeto json todos los campos y después buscar los duplicados. Primero creamos una copia del objeto this.addresses, le añadimos la dirección a incluir, creamos el indice y añadimos a duplicados, cada ocurrencia que se repita. Si duplicados tiene algo, es que hay valores duplicados, si no tiene nada es que no los hay y procedemos a añadir la dirección a nuestro objeto original.
El código quedaria algo así:

```
addAddress: function() {
    this.insertAddresses.Adress = this.address_address
    this.insertAddresses.State = this.selectedStateAddress
    this.insertAddresses.City = this.selectedCityAddress
    if (this.insertAddresses.Adress !== "" && this.insertAddresses.State !== null && this.insertAddresses.City !== null) {
        let copia = Object.assign({}, this.insertAddresses);
        const copiaobjeto = this.addresses;
        copiaobjeto.push(copia);
        const busqueda = copiaobjeto.reduce((acc, direccion) => {
            const clave = JSON.stringify(direccion);
            acc[clave] = ++acc[clave] || 0;
            return acc;
        }, {});
        const duplicados = copiaobjeto.filter((direccion) => {
            return busqueda[JSON.stringify(direccion)];
        });
        if (duplicados.length == 0) {
            this.addresses.push(copia)
        } else {
            this.$message.error('La dirección ya existe');
            return
        }
    } else {
        this.$message.error('Not enough data to add');
        return
    }
},
```

Comment: Imagino que te habrá servido porque se ha marcado la respuesta como válida, si es así me alegro, si tienes cualquier duda avisa. ;-)